# Check if number is decimal

Tags: php, function, decimal

I need to check in PHP if user entered a decimal number (US way, with decimal point: X.XXX)

Any reliable way to do this?

Comment: That is not a PHP function definition.

Comment: That is actionscript, not PHP.

Comment: Thanks for noticing, question edited. Sorry guys, sleepless nights made me find an AS function.

Comment: What is a decimal number in your eyes? Please add three examples to your question. Then please add three examples of non-decimal numbers you expect a user to input and you need to filter out.

Comment: Consider looking into how Zend validated a float: `Zend_Validate_Float`

Comment: Bear in mind that when using, for example, `<input type="number" min="0.00" max="100.00" step="0.01"... />`, some browsers will use "1" as the next incremental value after "0.99". For this reason, it may be worth considering rybo111's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20098294/1617737

Answer (score 125, accepted):

You can get most of what you want from [is_float](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-float.php), but if you *really* need to know whether it has a decimal in it, your function above isn't terribly far (albeit the wrong language):

```
function is_decimal( $val )
{
    return is_numeric( $val ) && floor( $val ) != $val;
}
```

Comment: @Felix Huh... I guess it didn't. In Python and ECMAScript, that is the best way to handle this. I swapped it for something which is more universal.

Comment: I just haven't seen it before, but it returned always `0` for me (in PHP). +1 for the updated :)

Comment: 10.00 for example still return false.

Comment: as it seems, "Night Owl" solution proposed will always work, including a "10.00" value.

Comment: This will fail for any decimal number that has only 0's after the decimal point, as @cyberfly points out. "10.00", "300.00000", etc., are all numeric (`true`). `floor($val)` = 10, 300, etc. And that `==` (weak comparison) $val. So you will get `false`. So I think Night Owl's solution is required.

Comment: @Felix Kling, a bit off-topic but to check whether a number has decimal values other than 0, this is sometimes used: `$val % 1` although this does not work in [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php): "Operands of modulus are converted to integers (by stripping the decimal part) before processing."

Comment: `floor( $val ) != $val` can be replaced with `is_float($val + 0)` adding the number zero to a string will force conversion into `float` or `int` depending on the result.

Answer (score 52):

*if you want "10.00" to return true check Night Owl's answer*

If you want to know if the decimals has a value you can use this answer.

Works with all kind of types **(int, float, string)**

```
if(fmod($val, 1) !== 0.00){
    // your code if its decimals has a value
} else {
    // your code if the decimals are .00, or is an integer
}
```

---

## Examples:

```
(fmod(1.00,    1) !== 0.00)    // returns false
(fmod(2,       1) !== 0.00)    // returns false
(fmod(3.01,    1) !== 0.00)    // returns true
(fmod(4.33333, 1) !== 0.00)    // returns true
(fmod(5.00000, 1) !== 0.00)    // returns false
(fmod('6.50',  1) !== 0.00)    // returns true
```

---

## Explanation:

[`fmod`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fmod.php) returns the floating point remainder (modulo) of the division of the arguments, (hence the (!== 0.00))

**Modulus operator** - why not use the modulus operator? E.g. `($val % 1 != 0)`

From the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php):

> Operands of modulus are converted to integers (by stripping the decimal part) before processing.

Which will effectively destroys the op purpose, in other languages like javascript you can use the modulus operator

Comment: `0.00` could be replaced with `0.0`. The extra zero does not do anything.

Answer (score 30):

If all you need to know is whether a decimal point exists in a variable then this will get the job done...

```
function containsDecimal( $value ) {
    if ( strpos( $value, "." ) !== false ) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This isn't a very elegant solution but it works with strings and floats.

Make sure to use !== and not != in the strpos test or you will get incorrect results.

Comment: Detecting a dot will not work if in a given language a comma "," is the decimal character. The user can format the number using `number_format()`.

Comment: detecting a decimal in a string is error prone. Take the [9th perfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Mersenne_primes_and_perfect_numbers) which is greater than PHP_INT_MAX, for example: `var_dump(2658455991569831744654692615953842176) => double(2.6584559915698E+36)` so a string value of that is obviously going to contain a decimal

Answer (score 11):

another way to solve this: `preg_match('/^\d+\.\d+$/',$number);` :)

Answer (score 7):

The function you posted is just not PHP.

Have a look at [`is_float` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-float.php).

**Edit:** I missed the "user entered value" part. In this case you can actually use a regular expression:

```
^\d+\.\d+$
```

Comment: That only checks for the type of the number, not the contents. So `is_float('1.14')` returns false.

Comment: Well, he talks about a user entered number, which is most likely a string. So it has to be converted to a number first.

Answer (score 5):

I was passed a string, and wanted to know if it was a decimal or not. I ended up with this:

```
function isDecimal($value) 
{
     return ((float) $value !== floor($value));
}
```

I ran a bunch of test including decimals and non-decimals on both sides of zero, and it seemed to work.

Comment: this method incorrectly returns false when you have a float like 0.0000

Answer (score 4):

`is_numeric` returns `true` for decimals and integers. So if your user lazily enters `1` instead of `1.00` it will still return `true`:

```
echo is_numeric(1); // true
echo is_numeric(1.00); // true
```

You may wish to convert the integer to a decimal with PHP, or let your database do it for you.

Comment: It's not necessarily a case of laziness. For example, using `<input type="number" min="0.00" max="100.00" step="0.01"... />`, some browsers will use "1" as the next incremental value after "0.99". For this reason, I'm using `is_numeric()` as I require a function that returns `true` for both "1" and "1.00".

Comment: Note that this doesn't catch strings like "10e4" which passes is_numeric() and automatically gets converted to 100000 in the database.

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment, but I have this interesting behaviour.
(tested on v. 7.3.19 on a website for php testing online)

If you multiply 50 by 1.1 fmod gives different results than expected.
If you do by 1.2 or 1.3 it's fine, if you do another number (like 60 or 40) is also fine.

```
$price = 50;
$price = $price * 1.1; 

if(strpos($price,".") !== false){
    echo "decimal";
}else{
    echo "not a decimal";
}

echo '<br />';

if(fmod($price, 1) !== 0.00){
    //echo fmod($price, 1);
    echo "decimal";
} else {
    echo "not a decimal";
}//end if
```

Comment: This is because of the floating point error, you can add "ini_set('precision', -1);"  to see what is going on  (it wont solve it)

Comment: Gives this a Lambo, strpos is a great idea. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 1):

This is a more tolerate way to handle this with user input. This regex will match both "100" or "100.1" but doesn't allow for negative numbers.

```
/^(\d+)(\.\d+)?$/
```

Answer (score 1):

i use this:

```
function is_decimal ($price){
  $value= trim($price); // trim space keys
  $value= is_numeric($value); // validate numeric and numeric string, e.g., 12.00, 1e00, 123; but not -123
  $value= preg_match('/^\d$/', $value); // only allow any digit e.g., 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9. This will eliminate the numeric string, e.g., 1e00
  $value= round($value, 2); // to a specified number of decimal places.e.g., 1.12345=> 1.12

  return $value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   // if numeric 

if (is_numeric($field)) {
        $whole = floor($field);
        $fraction = $field - $whole;

        // if decimal            
        if ($fraction > 0)
            // do sth
        else
        // if integer
            // do sth 
}
else

   // if non-numeric
   // do sth
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$lat = '-25.3654';

if(preg_match('/./',$lat)) {
    echo "\nYes its a decimal value\n";
}
else{
    echo 'No its not a decimal value';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A total cludge.. but hey it works !

```
$numpart = explode(".", $sumnum); 

if ((exists($numpart[1]) && ($numpart[1] > 0 )){
//    it's a decimal that is greater than zero
} else {
// its not a decimal, or the decimal is zero
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the easy way to find either posted value is integer and float so this will help you

```
$postedValue = $this->input->post('value');
if(is_numeric( $postedValue ) && floor( $postedValue ))
{
    echo 'success';
}
else
{
   echo 'unsuccess';
}
```

if you give 10 or 10.5 or 10.0 the result will be success if you define any character or specail character without dot it will give unsuccess

Answer (score 0):

How about `(int)$value != $value`?
If `true` it's decimal, if `false` it's not.

Answer (score -1):

Simplest solution is

```
if(is_float(2.3)){

 echo 'true';

}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are working with form validation. Then in this case form send string.
I used following code to check either form input is a decimal number or not.
I hope this will work for you too.

```
function is_decimal($input = '') {

    $alphabets = str_split($input);
    $find = array('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','.'); // Please note: All intiger numbers are decimal. If you want to check numbers without point "." then you can remove '.' from array. 

    foreach ($alphabets as $key => $alphabet) {
        if (!in_array($alphabet, $find)) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Check if user has enter "." point more then once.
    if (substr_count($input, ".") > 1) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function is_decimal_value( $a ) {
    $d=0; $i=0;
    $b= str_split(trim($a.""));
    foreach ( $b as $c ) {
        if ( $i==0 && strpos($c,"-") ) continue;
        $i++;
        if ( is_numeric($c) ) continue;
        if ( stripos($c,".") === 0 ) {
            $d++;
            if ( $d > 1 ) return FALSE;
            else continue;
        } else
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Known Issues with the above function:

1) Does not support "scientific notation" (1.23E-123), fiscal (leading $ or other) or "Trailing f" (C++ style floats) or "trailing currency" (USD, GBP etc)

2) False positive on string filenames that match a decimal: Please note that for example "10.0" as a filename cannot be distinguished from the decimal, so if you are attempting to detect a type from a string alone, and a filename matches a decimal name and has no path included, it will be impossible to discern.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe try looking into this as well

`!is_int()`