# PHP code returns value in float

Tags: php

In the following code, why does $final returns value as float?

**When the calculated value is 6, it should return as integer, otherwise float**.

How can I do that?

```
$x = 62;
$round = 5 * round($x / 5);
$final = $round/10;     
var_dump($final); 
float(6)
```

Edit: Sorry if my question is not clear. I need to find out if the $final has any decimal value or not. So in order to find out that, I was using is_float function, but that always returns true because above variable returns the value in float always. Hope my question is a bit more clear.

Comment: php types the variables along with their usage. There's no strong beforehand typing. You could use `intval` afterwards though. `(if intval($final) == $final)`...

Comment: So you have to check whether you got exactly 6 (and `intval($final)` that), otherwise got `float` ... where is the problem?

Comment: If you are working with float numbers you should consider using the BC Math functions - http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return type of `round` is float, as the [manual states](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php). You need to cast the result to integer:

```
$result = (integer) round($value);
```

---

Update:

Although I think a method should return either floats or integers and not change this depending on the result's value, you could try something like this:

```
if((integer) $result == $result) {
    $result = (integer) $result;
}
return $result;
```

Comment: This does not return float (as wanted by OP), if value is e.g. 6.21, it should(!) return as float.

Comment: how should the result of round being 6.21 ?

Comment: I understood the question like if the result is 6.00 return INT 6, if the result is 6.21, return float 6.21.

Comment: If you ask me, the question is questionable ;)

Comment: This is clear to me, at least me ;) ... "When the calculated value is 6, it should return as integer, otherwise float."

Comment: have changed my answer

Comment: @user2738640 check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6772603/php-check-if-number-is-decimal

Comment: I bet the question actually is to return only `0.21` if `6.21` is given ;) ... let's see/wait

Answer (score 1):

See this code live here:

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f8f383604cf848ab63534da69295f8482528e4ce

-

```
<?php

    $final = function($num) {

      $calc = (5 * ($num / 5)) / 10;

      if (intval($calc) == $calc) { settype($calc, "integer"); }
      else { settype($calc, "float"); } // might not need that line
      return $calc;
    };

    var_dump($final(62)); print '<br />';
    var_dump($final(60)); print '<br />';
    var_dump($final(59)); print '<br />';

?>
```

Besides, in the OPs code, this line (the `round()`)is incorrect:

```
$round = 5 * round($x / 5);
```

Comment: Thanks to myself for spending (did I say waisting?) my time on that ;)

Answer (score 0):

Little bit long, but something like this should do the trick

```
function ReturnType($FinalVal){
 switch (gettype($FinalVal)){
  case 'integer':
     return (int) $FinalVal;
  case 'double':
    return (float) $FinalVal;

 }
}

 $x = 62;
$round = 5 * round($x / 5);
$final = $round/10;     
$Value = ReturnType($final);
```

Comment: No, guess not correct, see http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/15acfa34c7aa54864c8f99d18bf517b981ecbd2d

Answer (score -1):

You must casting like this

```
$round = 5 * (int)(round($x / 5));
```

`round($x / 5)` returns float. If you don't cast it to int then the result would be float

Comment: and this was NOT the question ... it should return `int` or `float`, not only `int` ... `5* INT` is ... still `int`