# How to validate decimal variables with php?

Tags: php

I have a product in my sql table. From this product, the minimum order quantity is 19.2

If i want to add 19, the program allows it.

```
$product_id = intval($_POST['product_id']);
    $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
    $color = intval($_POST['szin']);
    $MinimumOrder = $_POST['MinimumOrder'];

    if($quantity%$MinimumOrder == 0 )
    {
        $cart->add($product_id, $quantity, array
            ( 
                "price" => $price,
                "color" => $color 
            )
        );

        echo 'A termék sikeresen hozzá lett adva a kosárhoz.';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Ebből a termékből csak egész raklap rendelhető. Egy raklapon  ' . $MinimumOrder . ' ' . $product['mertekegyseg_nev'] .' található.';
    }
```

Comment: `$MinimumOrder = $_POST['MinimumOrder'];`...you appear to be letting the client set the minimum order. So a knowledgeable user could simply change the value anyway. As validation, that's pretty useless (regardless of the issue with decimals). Validation needs to be controlled exclusively by the server.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6772603/check-if-number-is-decimal

Comment: maybe your database does not allow to record decimal values.

Comment: The data is stored in decimal, the field type is 10,2 decimal.

Answer (score 0):

PHP documentation says:

> Operands of modulo are converted to integers (by stripping the decimal part) before processing. For floating-point modulo, see fmod().

If you want to use 19.2, you will have to use the [fmod()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fmod.php) function

```
$MinimumOrder = 19.2;

$quantity = 19;
var_dump($quantity % $MinimumOrder);      // int(0)
var_dump(fmod($quantity, $MinimumOrder)); // int(19)

$quantity = 19.2;
var_dump(fmod($quantity, $MinimumOrder)); // int(0)

$quantity = 38.4;
var_dump(fmod($quantity, $MinimumOrder)); // int(0)

$quantity = 19.3;
var_dump(fmod($quantity, $MinimumOrder)); // int(0.1)

$quantity = 20;
var_dump(fmod($quantity, $MinimumOrder)); // int(0.8)
```