# Stylize woocommerce price decimals

Tags: php, woocommerce, price

I want to stylize the decimals in the price tag and want to delete zero decimals (before 190,00) and it should be (after 190,-)

And the decimals after the "," i want to make smaller as in this demo picture:

[image: demo]

So as first I wanted to delete the decimals with this line in functions.php

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_price_trim_zeros', '__return_true' );
```

Atleast it deleted the zero as it should be:

[image]

And this is how the price with decimals looks like witch i want to make smaller:

[image]

After some searching I found aa piece of code with it made it possible to make the decimals smaller. So I did this with this piece of code:

```
add_filter( 'formatted_woocommerce_price', 'ts_woo_decimal_price', 10, 5 );function ts_woo_decimal_price( $formatted_price, $price, $decimal_places, $decimal_separator, $thousand_separator ) {
$unit = number_format( intval( $price ), 0, $decimal_separator, $thousand_separator );
$decimal = sprintf( '%02d', ( $price - intval( $price ) ) * 100 );
return $unit . $decimal_separator. '<sup>' . $decimal . '</sup>';
```

}

So now the price looks good but the strange thing is, the price is 1 cent lower then before makeing it smaller!

[image]

The problem is now that the price where the zere decimals where gone, are now back again....

[image]

I checked google for hours and tried a lot of stuff, I really in trouble. I hope some one can put me in the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look at this answer [Check if number is decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6772603/check-if-number-is-decimal) **to check if the price is a decimal**.

Then you get the decimal part as an integer and put it inside the `<sup>` tag.

If you want, you can apply your own custom CSS style to the `<sup>` tag to format it as you wish.

**EDIT:** Fixed one-position decimal formatting error as reported by @ClawDuda.

```
// Edit the output by showing decimals with the HTML <sup> tag.
add_filter( 'formatted_woocommerce_price', 'custom_formatted_woocommerce_price', 10, 5 );
function custom_formatted_woocommerce_price( $formatted_price, $price, $decimal_number, $separator, $thousand_separator ) {
    // Gets the integer and decimal part of the product price.
    $raw_price = explode( $separator, $price );
    $int       = $raw_price[0];
    $decimals  = isset( $raw_price[1] ) ? $raw_price[1] : 0;
    // Edit the output.
    $formatted_price = '<span class="int">' . $int . $separator . '</span><sup>' . str_pad( $decimals, $decimal_number, '0', STR_PAD_RIGHT ) . '</sup>';
    return $formatted_price;
}
```

Output:

[image]

*The code has been tested and works. Add it to your active theme's functions.php.*

Comment: Vincenzo Thanks for the response! I tried to add it to my theme funcitons.php with results in price with the 2 decimals able to style trough css, but what do I need to fix when i want to add style to decimals but when the decimals are 00 that than the 2 zero's disapaer.

Comment: I set two zeros in case the price is full. See the `$decimals = '00';` line. You can modify this variable to change the decimals of an integer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Realy appreciatie it, looking for it for days!
I had to add a "-" sign after price. So I did it with your fix adding class to decimals:
`$decimals = '<span class="decimalentwee">-</span>';`

Comment: Hi. I found your answer very useful. I was wondering if you could point me on how to fix a "bug" in this code. In the cart for example, in case the decimals are .90 it will only display .9 so it skips the 0. Any idea on how to fix it ? Thank you

Comment: @ClawDuda I optimized the function and fixed the decimal formatting.