# Stylize woocommerce price decimals : issues

Tags: woocommerce

I'm using this snippet https://stackoverflow.com/a/66521763/15932569 but it has some issues. https://prnt.sc/13e8n4s
I'm trying to edit the floor operation.

```
add_filter( 'formatted_woocommerce_price', 'custom_formatted_woocommerce_price', 10, 5 );
function custom_formatted_woocommerce_price( $formatted_price, $price, $decimal_number, $separator, $thousand_separator ) {
    // if the price is float
    if ( floor( $price ) != $price ) {
        // gets the whole part
        $int = floor( $price );
        // gets the decimal part as an integer (based on the number of decimals set)
        $decimals = substr( $price, 0 , -2 );
    // if it is an integer
    } else {
        $int = $price;
        $decimals = '00';
    }
    // returns the price by separating the integer part from the decimals
    $formatted_price = '<span class="int">' . $int . $separator . '</span>' . $decimals ;
    return $formatted_price ;
    echo number_format($formatted_price, 2, ".", ",");
}
```

Do you have any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I did it. It works.

I'm not a developer so please add something or some warnings to the lines of code.

Thanks all.

```
add_filter( 'formatted_woocommerce_price', 'custom_formatted_woocommerce_price', 10, 5 );
function custom_formatted_woocommerce_price( $formatted_price, $price, $decimal_number, $separator, $thousand_separator ) {
   
        $int = number_format( intval( $price ), 0, $separator, $thousand_separator );
        $decimals = '00';
    
    // returns the price by separating the integer part from the decimals
    $formatted_price = '<span class="int">' . $int . $separator . '</span>' . $decimals ;
    return $formatted_price;
}
```